# Could not get visible text when using BeautifulSoup get_text or findAll(text=True)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract visible text from a webpage using bs4 and python 3.4.1. For this I'm extracting all script and style elements from my soup and then proceed to getting the text from the remaining html.

For testing purposes I used x,y,z to watch my soup modifications

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.skilledup.com/articles/reasons-to-learn-python').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib") #tried xml and html.parser also
x = soup.prettify()
for elem in soup.find_all(['script', 'style']): #I know the text between <title></title> tags could not be interpreted as 'visible text' but thats's not the point of this example
    elem.extract()
y = soup.prettify()
z1 = soup.find_all(text=True)
z2 = soup.get_text()
```

I see that x is the unchanged HTML, y is the same HTML without the script and style tags and that's correct.

z1 returns a ResultSet that still contains some html tags such as `<div class="category" id="article_top_name"></div>` AND also

```
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'skilledupblog';
/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
.... this continues with javascript
```

z2 is the most cleaner version of what I'm trying to accomplish and gets me all the visible text but still contains, in the end of the string, parts of one javascript like this one:

```
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'skilledupblog';
/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
.... this continues with javascript
```

This is not an isolated case as I've seen similar results for different html pages I try to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still got the same results when using the initial configuration (bs4 and python 3.4.1) but by Using Python 2.7.8 or Python 35-32 I get the clear expected HTML without any script and/or style tags. Not sure what might have been the cause but this works.

Answer (score 2):

Removing all `script` and `style` elements and then getting the text of the `soup` worked for me:

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.skilledup.com/articles/reasons-to-learn-python').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

for elem in soup.find_all(['script', 'style']):
    elem.extract()

print(soup.get_text())
```

In the printed text, there is no `disqus_shortname` or any other parts of the `script` elements that you've mentioned.